# Visit link on list of Proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51

It would be nice, if direct link for stackexchange site will be on list of proposals

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Popular Demand: I think @MicTech is suggesting links for launched sites being directly on the Area51 home page; i.e. not requiring a click through to the detail page for a site that's already been launched.